# Uniqueness of Vectors

Tags: matrix, vector

This question is in two parts:

I have a series of large vectors (where each vector comprises of values 0 and 1) that I have then concatenated into one large matrix.

1. What I first want to know is how 'unique' (or the opposite, how 'distinct') each vector/row is compared to all other vectors.
2. What I also want to do is look at each vector 'column' to see if their value is predicted by some other dependent variable (ie how discriminant is each column in identifying another binary variable value ). It may also be a certain set of columns is most predictive, but again I am not sure how to derive this.

If you know especially the way to do this in R, that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: That you refer to a "dependent variable" makes me think you are doing some kind of regression. While I am interested in this question on its own, I do wonder if this is part of an attempt to solve some regression problem, in which case, there might be established methods for solving the problem you really want to solve (i.e., the XY problem).